# About the image size that generated from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generated a histogram by using matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as P


mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*P.randn(10000)


P.figure()
bins = 10
n, bins, patches = P.hist(x, bins, normed=1, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
P.show()
```

I want to make the picture smaller, how could I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to set it for this specific figure, then change your figure declaration to:

```
P.figure(figsize=(i,j))
```

where i is the width in inches and j is the height in inches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying the figsize, there's also a dpi option - although this is more important if you're using one of the image generating backends.